# What will happend if run this command `gzip -r filename .`?

Tags: centos, gzip

I ran this `gzip -r filename .`

It zipped `filename` to `fielname.gz` and all the `.`(dotfiles/hidden files) in all the directories.

1. Is this the expected behaviour?
2. How to undo gz of `.`(dotfiles/hidden files)?

Comment: Have you checked to see if you still have your dot files, still in their original places? What did gzip interpret the `.` on the command line as?